# dynamic number of id's when select with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, dynamic, parameters, numbers

Im making a site where i need to select from DB with dynamic nuber of Id's and im using entity framework so my problem is instead of doing this

```
IQueryable source = content.Products;

List<Object> o = new List<Object>();

foreach(int ID in IDS)
 o.Add(content.Where(s => s.id == ID).FirstOrDefault()); // getting the row from DB   foreach loop
```

Instead of this i would like to get all the Entitys from DB with dynamic number of IDs Like

```
o = content.Where(s = s.id == ID || s.id == ID || s.ID == ID).ToList();
```

But the where condition needs to be dynamic like a string so i can add the ids from a loop and then make the select like

```
string s = "where ";

foreach(int id in ids)
s += " id = " + id + " or ";

o = content.Where(s).ToList;
```

so i access the DB only once instead of i need to access several times for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Contains` for this:

```
List<Product> o = content.Where(s => ids.Contains(s.id)).ToList();
```

It translates into a SQL `IN` clause and loads all products with the given `ids` in a single query.

Comment: @user1518729: An `IEnumerable` of your `Product.ID` type, so yes, a `List<int>` is possible. I've just taken the `ids` from your code, or maybe `IDS`, you have mixed that in your question.